# How do i pass a div id into a php pagination url here is my code example

Tags: php, html

I have a div id=example in html the url would be [www.mysite.com#example](http://www.mysite.com#example). Now i want to refer that in php url below with index#example

```
<?php
        if($page <=1 )
        {
            echo '<span id="page_links" style="font-weight:bold;"> &#124;&#124; </span>&ensp;';
        }
        else
        {
            $j = $page- 1;
            echo '<span><a id="page_a_link" href="index?&page=' . $j . '" style="color:#ac5f42"> Prev </a></span>&ensp;';
        }
        for($i=1; $i <= $total_pages; $i++)
        {
            if($i<>$page)
            {
              echo '<span><a href="index?&page=' .$i. '" id="page_a_link" style="color:#5fbf7f">' . $i . '</a></span> &ensp;';
            }
            else
            {
                echo '<span id="page_links" style="font-weight:bold;">' . $i . '</span>&ensp;';
            }
        }
        if($page == $total_pages )
        {
            echo '<span id="page_links" style="font-weight:bold;">&#124;&#124;</span>&ensp;';
        }
        else
        {
            $j = $page + 1;
            echo '<span><a href="index?&page=' .$j. '" id="page_a_link" style="color:#ac5f42"> Next </a></span>';
        }
    
?>
```

Comment: PHP doesn't get or see the `#` part of a URL. That's purely for the browser. If you want to pass some parameter to PHP in the url, you need to use the a query parameter: `?div=example` or similar.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson i tried using $_GET['id'] inside the url/ anchor tag it doesn't work

Comment: Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We need way more information than that to know what you're actually doing.

Comment: i have a <section id="example"> and my php page <a href="index?&page='  after index is where the url should direct to which is the "example" id

Comment: @the_guru your URL like this <a href="index?div=example&page=1"> then you can get $_GET['div']  = example.

Comment: Please read the links i posted properly and edit your question accordingly. I wouldn't call your comment "way more information". I don't know what you expect `$_GET['id']` to return when you haven't mentioned how you pass that value (it would be `id=xxx` in the URL). Also, it should be `?page=` not `?&page=`. The `&` should be between the different values, but not before the first.

Answer (score 1):

I got this somewhere here on stackoverflow and it answered my question perfectly

```
    <script>
if (window.location.hash == "") {
      window.location = window.location + "#sectionid";
}
</script>
```

my url became `<a href="'.$_GET['sectionid'].'?&page=' .$j. '" id="page_a_link" style="color:#ac5f42"> Next </a>`

Thanks Stackoverflow after weeks of looking for solution!!!!